# Content-Type not changing in Node.js with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I'm trying to create a webhook that sends XML data via the POST method to my Node.js application. I'm simply trying to get the data that it is sending, the problem is that it stays in application/json content-type no matter what I do. This is causing the data not to be shown. I can force the headers when I send out the POST request (and it works fine), but I will not have control over this on production. Not sure what else to try.

Below is the code that I currently have.

`server.js`

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'), app = express();

const xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');

app.use(xmlparser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  res.header('Accept', 'application/xml');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  res.set('Accept','application/xml');
  next();
});

app.post('/webhook',function(request, response) {
  response.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  response.header('Accept','application/xml');
  response.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  response.set('Accept','application/xml');
  console.log('running webhook');
  console.log(request.headers);
  response.end();
});
```

`package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.8.0",
    "express-xml-bodyparser": "^0.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
```

In `request.headers` object I get (note the content-type):

```
{ host: '{MYURLHERE}',
  'content-length': '4429',
  accept: 'application/json',
  origin: 'chrome-extension://ecjfcmddigpdlehfhdnnnhfgihkmejin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  dnt: '1',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  cookie: '',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-port': '443',
  'x-region': 'usw',
  'x-forwarded-for': 'XX.XX.X.XXX',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers that you are logging are from your Chrome Extension, since there are no overrides set it will use the defaults and that is why you logs never change. They are coming from your browser.

In your case you need to either set headers on the Chrome extension or if the web hook needs them you need to spin up a new request and set the Headers there.

Below is an example of how to use `setHeaders`.

On your `Post` it should be

```
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  response.setHeader('Accept','application/xml');
```

Comment: I just tried it on `app.post` and `app.use`. No change. Still same headers and nothing inside `body`.

Comment: What is sending to this node app? That would be setting it's headers that you are seeing in request header.

Comment: On development, I'm using `Rest Web Service Client` extension for Google Chrome and I'm not setting headers there. I'm simply targeting my webhook and sending sample XML.

Comment: Right the above code is logging the `headers` from your chrome extension hence why it is the defaults of the `request`. You are setting the response headers, which is what you would be responding with to the request.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, in my response from the extension I get the right content-type back. But that does nothing for me on incoming requests on my application. Is there any way I can set headers for incoming requests?

Comment: Your Rest Web Service Client can set them. If the Hook needs them then you need to either proxy the request or spin up a new request and set the headers there.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I was just approaching this the wrong way. I made sure the production side of things was sending out the correct content-type and it was. Lesson learned.